# What happens in this class?

Tags: python, class

I am trying to alter a program, but i first need to fully understand the code.

```
class Coordinate: 
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def equal_to(self,coordinate):
        return coordinate.x == self.x and coordinate.y == self.y

    def merge_together(self,coordinate_together):
        return Coordinate(self.x+coordinate_together.x,self.y+coordinate_together.y)
```

What is the functionality of this class?

I can't understand -- especially the `return coordinate.x` and `coordinate.y` parts.

Comment: It seems to me "equal_to" says it all. It tests whether one coordinate instance and another are equal.

Comment: Could you be clearer on what precisely you do and do not understand? I would expect to see `__eq__` rather than `equal_to` (and maybe `__add__` rather than `merge_together`) - where did this code come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::merge_together` sums (Euclidean translation) the ordinates, returning a new `Coordinate` instance.

`::equal_to` compares two `Coordinate` objects (but perhaps should be using the `__eq__` idiom  -- along with related methods).

Comment: what does the equal_to function return?

Comment: @Pieter have you considered trying it and seeing?

Comment: A `bool` consisting of the logical equality of the `Coordinate`s (this one -- `self` and `coordinate`, passed in).  `True` if they're the same.

Answer (score 0):

it returns `True` if `coordinate.x == self.x` AND `coordinate.y == self.y`. 
(looks like same position)

The method expects and instance of `Coordinate` probably (see below the same object)